# Ошибка сборки докера

Tags: docker

Выходит ошибка сборки образа докера при попытке его собрать.

Докер файл питона:

```
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1
FROM python:3.9

WORKDIR /app

COPY requirements.txt /app
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt

EXPOSE 5000

COPY . /app
```

Когда хочу собрать выскакивает ошибка:

```
#0 4.595 Collecting click==8.0.4
#0 4.664   Downloading click-8.0.4-py3-none-any.whl (97 kB)
#0 4.678      ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 97.5/97.5 KB 9.0 MB/s eta 0:00:00
#0 4.766 ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement command-not-found==0.3 (from versions: none)
#0 4.766 ERROR: No matching distribution found for command-not-found==0.3
#0 5.143 WARNING: You are using pip version 22.0.4; however, version 22.2.2 is available.
#0 5.143 You should consider upgrading via the '/usr/local/bin/python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

Структура проекта:

MyApp:

- app

  - Dockerfile #(докер-файл питона)
  - requirements.txt
- docker-compose.dev.yml

---

В чем проблема м/б? Что не так?

Дополнение (через PowerShell).

Показываю то, что просили в комментариях (хотя не понимаю зачем это все, ведь сборка докера идет в Ubuntu и все что тут ниже покажу - это вроде как никаким образом не должно влиять на сборку докера. Хотя, может и заблуждаюсь.)

> pip --version

```
pip 22.2.2 from C:\...\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip (python 3.10)
```

> python --version

```
Python 3.10.5
```

Comment: Какой-то пакет `command-not-found` не может найти под вашу систему, видимо

Comment: @Алексей Белкин `sudo apt-get install command-not-found` Покажи, что пишет, если эту команду запустить.

Comment: @Алексей Белкин Попробуй обновить pip `sudo pip3 install --upgrade pip` 
Если ты используешь Python 3 версии, то ты должен использовать pip3.
Или так попробуй обновить: `sudo apt-get install python3-pip`

Comment: @Vladimir Glinskikh, sudo в докерах вроде как не прописывается. Или я чего-то не знаю?

Comment: @АлексейБелкин Да не в докере, а в терминале пропиши. :) Я так понял у тебя различаются версии Python и Pip (стандартный менеджер пакетов для Python).

Comment: @АлексейБелкин Покажи, что показывает команда: `pip --version`, `python --version`.

Comment: @АлексейБелкин Когда ты устанавливаешь новую среду, используя файл requirments.txt, pip ищет последнюю версию, которая удовлетворяет требованию, и устанавливает ее. Ты можешь попробовать  обновить пакеты в своем файле требований, выполнив команду install с ключом--upgrade и показать ошибки тут, если будут:
`pip install --upgrade -r requirements.txt`

Comment: @Vladimir Glinskikh, сделал с этим ключом, ошибка та же. Ничего не поменялось. + Внес дополнение - там нагляднее все.